# Trying to Build a Heart Rate Sensor with Arduino

Tags: javascript, processing, sensors, arduino-uno

I'm really new to programming, but really wanted to try this project. So, I'm using code that has already been written. I have a brand new Arduino Uno, and a Pulse Sensor. The pin 13 LED wouldn't stop blinking, but I finally adjusted the code to output only low voltage to it. And eventually, I got the Arduino sketch where I think it should be. BUT- Whenever I run processing, the heart rate is crazy without me even touching it (when I do touch it, it just does nothing) and at the bottom of the sketch is says something about an error disabling  serialEvent for the usb modem I'm trying to use.

```
    This program functions as a data visualizer for the Pulse Sensor
    Serial input is designed to mate with arduino sketch "A_PulseSensor_xx"
    This code made by Joel Murphy and Yury Gitman in Brooklyn, Summer 2011.

    interactive features in this version:
    press 'S' or 's' to take a picture of the data window. (.tif image)

    import processing.serial.*;      // this is how we talk to arduino
    PFont font, rateFont, smallFont;            // create font instances
    Serial port;                     // create and name the serial port

    int heart = 0;            // used to time pulsing of heart graphic with your heart beat
     int pulseRate = 0;        // used to hold pulse rate value sent from arduino (beats per minute)
    int Sensor = 0;           // used to hold raw sensor data from arduino
    int HRV;                  // time between this current beat and the last    beat in mS (used for Heart Rate Variability) 
int Ypos;                 // used to print the new Pulse Sensor data point
int[] pulseY;                 // used to hold pulse waveform Y positions
int[] rateY;                 // used to hold bpm waveform Y positions
// these variables will hold pulse window specs
int PulseWindowMin;
int PulseWindowMax;        
int PulseWindowW;
int PulseWindowH;
int PulseWindowY;
int PulseWindowX;
int PulseDisplayBaseline = 712;  // these variables are used to adjust the pulse window display 
int PulseOffset = 712;           // the max and min will auto adjust if the waveform drifts beyond the screen

color eggshell = color(255,253,248); // offwhite color for data display windows
color R = color(250,0,0);            // red color for datapoints and heart graphic
int grey = 80;                       // grey color for numeric data windows

boolean beat = false;            // used to advance heart rate graph
boolean newRate = false;         // used to update heart rate display


void setup() {
size(800,600); // Stage size
frameRate(100); // refresh rate
font = loadFont("Arial-BoldMT-36.vlw");  // font for small text
rateFont = loadFont("Arial-BoldMT-80.vlw");  // font for larger text
smallFont = loadFont("Arial-BoldMT-14.vlw"); // font for smaller text
textFont(font); // set up to print small font
textAlign(RIGHT);  // referemce points
rectMode(CENTER);

//  define the size of the pulse window
PulseWindowW = 710;    // width of pulse window
PulseWindowH = 400;    // height of pulse window
PulseWindowX = width/2+30;  // center X coordinate of pulse window
PulseWindowY = height-225;  // center Y coordinate of pulse window 
PulseWindowMin = PulseWindowY - PulseWindowH/2;  // top Y position of pulse window
PulseWindowMax = PulseWindowY + PulseWindowH/2;  // bottom Y position of pulse window

pulseY = new int[PulseWindowW+1];    // array to hold Y coordinate of pulse datapoints
rateY = new int[320];                // array to hold y coordinate of heart rate datapoints




// find and establish contact with the serial port
println(Serial.list());       // print a list of available serial ports
port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[3], 115200); // choose the right one in square brackets
port.bufferUntil('\n');          // arduino will end each ascii string with a '\n' at the end (carriage return)
port.clear();                    // flush the serial buffer



// set arbitrary initial data position at top of pulse window
Ypos = PulseWindowMin;    
for (int i = 0; i < pulseY.length; i++){  
  pulseY[i] = PulseWindowMin;  
}

// set the BPM visualizer line to 0
 for (int i=0; i<rateY.length; i++){
    rateY[i] = 162;      // 162 is the pixel height for 0 heart rate
   }
}


void draw(){

printScreen();      // DRAW THE MAJOR SCREEN COMPONENTS AND TEXT

// THESE ARE THE PULSE SENSOR WAVEFORM DRAWING ROUTINES
// fisrt, move the Y coordintae of previous pulse data points over one pixel to the left
 for (int i = 0; i < pulseY.length-1; i++){  
   pulseY[i] = pulseY[i+1];     
 }
// new data enters on the right of the screen. sensor value is placed in the last array position
pulseY[pulseY.length-1] = Ypos;  // Ypos is updated in the serialEvent tab
// This for loop renders the Pulse Sensor waveform
 for (int x = 1; x < pulseY.length-1; x++){    // variable 'x' will take the place of pixel x position
   stroke(R);                                  // get ready to make a red line
// Here are a few ways to draw the datapoints.    
//   line(x+61, pulseY[x]+1, x+61, pulseY[x]-1);          // display previous datapoint as vertical line
//   point(x+61,pulseY[x]);                               //display previous datapoint as point
//   ellipse(x+61,pulseY[x],1,1);                         // display previous datapoint as a small dot
   line(x+76, pulseY[x], x+75, pulseY[x-1]);              //display previous datapoint as a connected line
 }


//  THESE ARE THE HEART RATE DRAWING ROUTINES 
 if (beat == true){   // only move the heart rate line over once every time the heart beats (beat flag set in serialEvent tab)
   beat = false;      // reset beat flag
   for (int i=0; i<rateY.length-1; i++){
    rateY[i] = rateY[i+1];      // shif the bpm Y coordinates over one pixel to the left
   }
 }
// update the BPM display Y coordinate when arduino sends a new calculation
 if (newRate == true){                          // when the new rate is sent from arduino 
   float dummy = map(pulseRate,0,200,135,10);   // map it to the heart rate window Y
   rateY[rateY.length-1] = int(dummy);          // set the rightmost pixel to the new data point value
 }
// print out the graph of the heart rate
 stroke(250,0,0);                                     // color of heart rate graph
 for (int x=0; x < rateY.length-1; x++){        // variable 'x' will take the place of pixel x position
   line(x+76, rateY[x]+2, x+76, rateY[x]-2);    // display previous heart rate datapoint as vertical line
 }
}  //end of draw loop




void printScreen(){          // DRAW MAJOR SCREEN ELEMENTS AND TEXT
   background(0);                           // black background
   noStroke();  
   fill(grey);                              // grey
   rect(40,PulseWindowY,70,PulseWindowH);   // draw box around pulse window numbers  
   rect(40,90,70,150);                      // draw box around rate window numbers  
   fill(eggshell);                          // eggshell
   rect(PulseWindowX,PulseWindowY,PulseWindowW,PulseWindowH);        // draw pulse terminal
   rect(235,90,320,150);                                             // draw bpm terminal
   text("0",65,163);                        // print ʻ0ʻ at bottom of bpm terminal (min heart rate for zombies)
   text("200",65,35);                       // print ʻ200ʻ at top of bpm terminal (max heart rate for young runners) 
   text(HRV,65,PulseWindowY);              // print the waveform amplitude
   text("BPM",width-215,100);               // clarification (BPM = Beats Per Minute = heart rate)
   text("Pulse Sensor Visualizer 0.6",width-35,160);      // name of program, version   
   textFont(smallFont);
   text("mS Time",72,PulseWindowY + 20);
   text("Between",72,PulseWindowY + 40);  // print the high number of visible datapoints (DEPENDS ON AUTO OFFSET)
   text("Beats",72,PulseWindowY + 60);      // print the low number of   visible datapoints  (DITTO)   
   textFont(rateFont);                      // set up to print large text
   text(pulseRate,width-275,100);           // print out the pulse rate 
   textFont(font);                          // set up to print small text


// DRAW THE HEART AND MAYBE MAKE IT BEAT
  fill(250,0,0);
  stroke(250,0,0);
  heart--;                    // the heart variable is used to time how long the heart graphic swells when your heart beats
  if (heart < 0){heart = 0;}  // don't let the heart variable go into              negative numbers
      if (heart > 0){             // if a beat happened recently, 
      strokeWeight(8);          // make the heart big
      }
     smooth();   // draw the heart with two bezier curves
      bezier(width-125,30, width-45,-40, width-25,120, width-125,130);
      bezier(width-125,30, width-215,-40, width-225,120, width-125,130);
      strokeWeight(1);        // reset the strokeWeight

    }  // END OF printScreen FUNCTION

    //  original heart design and positioning
    //  bezier(width-150,50, width-70,-20, width-50,140, width-150,150);
    //  bezier(width-150,50, width-230,-20, width-250,140, width-150,150);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the full code, but I'll assume the serialEvent tab is the same as the [example code](https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensor_Amped_Processing_Visualizer/blob/master/PulseSensorAmpd_Processing_1dot1/serialEvent.pde). If that's the case, you can try something like this:

```
boolean isConnected;
void serialEvent(Serial port){ 
  try{
   String inData = port.readStringUntil('\n');
   inData = trim(inData);                 // cut off white space (carriage return)

   if (inData.charAt(0) == 'S'){          // leading 'S' for sensor data
     inData = inData.substring(1);        // cut off the leading 'S'
     Sensor = int(inData);                // convert the string to usable int
   }
   if (inData.charAt(0) == 'B'){          // leading 'B' for BPM data
     inData = inData.substring(1);        // cut off the leading 'B'
     BPM = int(inData);                   // convert the string to usable int
     beat = true;                         // set beat flag to advance heart rate graph
     heart = 20;                          // begin heart image 'swell' timer
   }
   if (inData.charAt(0) == 'Q'){            // leading 'Q' means IBI data 
     inData = inData.substring(1);        // cut off the leading 'Q'
     IBI = int(inData);                   // convert the string to usable int
   }
   println("Sensor: " + Sensor + "\tBPM: " + BPM + "\tIBI: " + IBI);
   isConnected = ((IBI >= 300 && IBI <= 1100) && (Sensor >= 200 && Sensor <= 975) && (BPM >= 30 && BPM <= 120));
  }catch(Exception e){
    println("caught error parsing data:");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The [try](https://processing.org/reference/try.html)...catch block is to catch potential parsing errors. Depending on when you connect the sensor and when you open the sketch you might miss a char or two which may throw off the next lines parsing a string that's not fully there. Not the cleanest solution, but it should help.

Also notice the isConnected variable above. That's something you could use to do something about the data or display content only when valid data is available. If you're sensor is not connected, it will still send data, but it will be invalid and unusable. The variable is updated which each read, taking the 3 variables into account: IBI (time between peaks in millis), Sensor(raw sensor value), BPM(averaged BPM). The numbers there aren't a solution, but a hint at one way of filtering the data. Feel free to play with the values and conditions to obtain the results that work best for your setup.

Comment: Thanks--- @GeorgeProfenza, where would I add that to, or its it instead of?

Comment: Use the code above to replace the code in the serialEvent tab of the sketch. Please go through the whole example code and try to understand it. It will help you on the long run. the serialEvent tab is the where the arduino to processing serial communication takes part

Comment: You can change the fill colour of the heart shape for example depending on the value of the isConnected variable.